# Oracle different Results between sqldeveloper and PHP

Tags: php, oracle

i got a very interessting problem with Oracle and PHP. With PHP i didn't get actual data. I was able to do a update with the form, but still get the old data in the edit page and overview, with different Browser, without Cache on. In SQLdeveloper the data are right .... is there a problem with php and oracle ?

[image: SQLdeveloper]

[image: PHP]

Comment: where is the difference between the sql-developer select and then php form?  the values on the screenshorts apear to be the same

Comment: NAME_GRETA_KURZ is "test" to "TEST funktioniert" and NAME_GRETA_LANG is "ttest" to "test", "test" and "ttest" were the old values

Answer (score 0):

the problem was commit, there seems to be no autocommit with php

there is a php function for this

```
$r = oci_commit($conn);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($conn);
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}
oci_close($conn);
```